Отправил данные на сервер, как получить ответ?
Всем привет. мой стек: node.js - frontend, php - backend, nginx - сервер, я отправляю с клиентской части через форму какие-то данные:
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8080" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="pass"/><br/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

action перебрасывает на страницу сервера то есть на http://127.0.0.1:8080, а фронт у меня на 3000 порту.
<?php
var_dump($_GET);

На странице, на которую меня перекидывает вижу массив данных, который я отправил с фронтенда. Допустим я сделаю манипуляции с этими данными на бэке, а как мне отправить данные обратно на фронтенд?
Поднимаю весь проект с помощью docker и docker-compose

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

var_dump($_GET); уже отправил данные на фронтенд

@u_mulder ньет :) "Папа у него  у него - голубь!" В смысле у него "клиент", "фронтенд" на ноде, и бэкенд. И запрашивает он с "клиента" бэкенд. Который и возвращает данные на "клиента", не а на "фронтенд".

@Даниил а зачем тебе этот "фронтенд", мил человек? А если уж он используется, то с клиента надо на него обращаться. А не на бэкенд.

@Ипатьев я давно уже не видел фронтенды, но полагаю что на 3000-м порту у него крутится нодовый девсервер, что мониторит изменения в файлах и билдит. А в готовом приложении никаких нод уже не будет.
